# How to Use Internalization i18n in a Controller in SAPUI5?

Tags: internationalization, sapui5

Could anyone please explain how it's possible to use an `i18n` text in a `setValueStateText` method in a controller?

```js
oTP.setValueStateText("{i18n>co_Maximal_60_h}");
```

The error message in the dialog shows only `{i18n>co_Maximal_60_h}` and not the real text.

Comment: which control do you use? and is it in a view or a controller?

Comment: in this case a MaskInput. yes, it is in a controller! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The resource bundle is in the following way accessible in a controller:

```js
const oResourceBundle = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();

oTP.setValueStateText(oResourceBundle.getText("co_Maximal_60_h"));
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot set the binding string via setter method.
Here you have 2 options:

1. to set the binding right in the view (use the same string but in XML)
2. to utilize the [`ResourceBundle`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/module:sap/base/i18n/ResourceBundle):

```js
const oResourceBundle = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();
    
const sTxt = oResourceBundle.getText("co_Maximal_60_h");
        
oTP.setValueStateText(sTxt);
```

I'd recommend to add a reusable method to your `BaseController` with a name `i18n`, so whenever you need it, call `this.i18n("i18n_key")`.